# Partition drive becomes FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF after erasing Linux partition

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, startup

I didn’t make a backup and want to recover files from my Mac.

I have an internal SSD on my Mac and I have allocated 20GB of it for my Linux. I erased the 20GB Linux on disk utility and wished to free that volume for Mac main volume but the minus sign grayed out after erasing (formatting) the Linux volume.

When I restart the computer, it boots into GNU GRUB version 2.02 and gets stuck into a loop even with exit command. I try booting with option but there’s only one available disk to choose from, which is EFI volume and it leads mot the GNU terminal.

I then boot into recovery mode and noticed the main partition is showing the FFFF… as contents and partition type. Please see the photos for reference.

I didn’t backup (yes I’m dumb…) my drive before erasing Linux and really hope I can recovery the lost data on Mac. I don’t care the Linux data at all.

I noticed there are some old questions similar to my problem but I’m unsure if the code/numbers are the same as most of them are few years old.

Thanks in advance!

gpt output
[image: gpt output]

diskutil info output
[image]

fdisk output
[image]

disk0s2 info
[image]

I didn’t backup (yes I’m dumb…) my drive before erasing Linux and really hope I can recovery the lost data on Mac. I don’t care the Linux data at all. Is this possible to repair or do I need professional help?

---

Update:

1. I am able to modify the GUID partition map from existing questions on the forum but the GNU GRUB terminal still shows when it starts up. I am able to bypass that with exit command and get to normal Apple login screen. Once I have entered my password, the screen turns into a terminal-like screen with the Apple loading bar in between as shown below.

[image]

2. Also, I notice there is a size of 144 block (512-byte) not being assigned after I have added back my Mac data block (disk0s2). How can I safely include that block back to my main partition?

[image]

3. At the very beginning, I was trying to remove my Linux partition and convert that back to my main Mac partition on Disk Utility as per Apple's construction but that caused this whole issue. I formatted that into FAT32, which is not correct. How should I safely remove that FAT32 and include the ~20GB back to my main partition?

[image]

Comment: Please use Search before posting - https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=ffffffff

Comment: @Tetsujin I am able to modify the GUID partition map with previous questions but the GNU GRUB terminal is still showing when it starts up, I am able to bypass that with exit command and get to normal Apple login screen. Once I entered my password, the screen turned into a terminal-like screen with the Apple loading bar in between. I have updated the question with a picture of that. Would you able to help on that?